# Socket.io listeners in React class component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

The socket.io event listener in the below code isn't working. Any ideas?

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      socket: io("localhost:5000")
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.socket.on("event", data => {console.log("event logged.")})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It might be worth noting that "foo" here is the child of a functional component which is also using socket.io listeners, but with hooks (useEffect). The socket.io event listeners in the parent component are working just fine.

Comment: Class name should be written in capital letters, you can find it in the docs

Comment: @LazarNikolic my bad, missed it in the pseudocode here

Comment: I dont think we can help you unles you share a bot more of your code. Could you maybe put here package.json and also parent component of the one you posted here?

Comment: gonna leave this question up just in case, but I ended up moving everything into a functional component and using hooks.